# how to retry download jar except delete all the download content for the jar?

Tags: java, maven

While doing a build last night, it stopped part way through since it 
failed to download an artifact dependency.    I pulled up my web browser 
and had a look at the directory contents of 
www.ibiblio.org/maven/avalon/jars and the logtkit 1.2.2.jar was 
present.  So I assume that I experienced a network disruption.

Is there a way to have maven retry the download if it receives an 
exception?   I can understand not retrying if the server specifically 
returns a 404.

what's more , I know if I delete related jar content in .m2 dir it can retry,but, I think it isn't the best methods?

if there any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `-U` to `mvn` it will force update

```
 -U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for updated
                                        releases and snapshots on remote
                                        repositories
```